# Assert arrays in Protractor

Tags: arrays, compare, jasmine, protractor, assertions

I am working on E2E tests and my goal is to compare two arrays. I set these arrays so that they are identical. The problem is that Protractor doesn't think they are same.

My code:

> expect(arrPuv).toBe(arrNov);

Console output:

> Error: Expected [ '1 patro', '2. Patro', 'asdf', 'My precious', 'My precious', 'My precious', 'My precious' ] to be [ '1 patro', '2. Patro', 'asdf', 'My precious', 'My precious', 'My precious', 'My precious' ].

How can I compare them correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This actually goes down to how are you making the expectation. `toBe()` would make sure both arrays are *the same object*. Instead, you need to *compare values*, use `toEqual()`:

```
expect(arrPuv).toEqual(arrNov);
```

See also:

- [Jasmine JavaScript Testing - toBe vs toEqual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413009/jasmine-javascript-testing-tobe-vs-toequal)

Comment: Thank you alecxe, I didn't know that. Your answer is more right than mine.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I got it working by stringifying the arrays:

> arrPuv = arrPuv.toString();
>
> arrNov = arrNov.toString();
>
> expect(arrPuv).toBe(arrNov);