# I can't get right elements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, angular-elements

I click the sort button, get all prices, and I need to ensure that elements were sorted correctly by prices. So I need to get price value="377",  price value="1288",  price value="1688" etc. but I can't get the right elements.

```
<div class="ssl-price-box">
    <price value="377" units="/yr" class="lg-price ng-isolate-scope">
        <span class="price">
            <span class="currency-icon">$</span>
            <span class="integer ng-binding">3.</span>
            <span class="cent ng-binding">77</span>
            <span class="units">/yr</span>
        </span>
    </price>
    <!-- ngIf: product.prices.max.certIsPromo -->
</div>
<div class="ssl-content">
    <div class="ssl-price-box">
        <price value="1288" units="/yr" class="lg-price ng-isolate-scope">
            <span class="price">
                <span class="currency-icon">$</span>
                <span class="integer ng-binding">12.</span>
                <span class="cent ng-binding">88</span>
                <span class="units">/yr</span>
            </span>
        </price>
```

i tried search be css, className, xpath, repearet, i thought if they are all the same repeater would work.
My code:

```
const allSSLList = $$('.ssl-price-box');
const newAllSSLList = allSSLList.sort((a, b)=>a-b));

expect(await allSSLList).toBe(massiveOfElements)
```

I need to get only prices, e.g. "3.77", "12.88", "16.88" etc. and then verify if they are ASC sorting but I got all prices, even old ones. I need to get only where

```
<span class="price">
    <price value="377" units="/yr" class="lg-price ng-isolate-scope">
```

Expected [ '$3.77/YR', '$12.88/YR $26.99/YR', '$16.88/YR $31.99/YR', '$19.66/YR $35.88/YR', '$30.88/YR $44.99/YR', '$38.88/YR $95.99/YR', '$59.99/YR', '$68.88/YR $138.99/YR', '$70.88/YR $96.99/YR', '$78.19/YR', '$78.19/YR', '$134.99/YR', '$138.88/YR $215.89/YR' ] to be 'smth'.
  Stack:

Comment: You are using incorrect locators. Your DOM doesn't have any 'ng-app'

Comment: what locator should i use?

Comment: I would say the question is too broad. This is why here is my broad answer - assign elementArrauyFinder to a variable, that points to all elements you need (you may check it in browser's devtools), `.getText()` of it OR `.getAttribute("attribute")` whichever you need, and only then you can sort these values and compare if sorted array matches unsorted

Comment: thanks, first o f all i need extract correct data, because i get all prices, even that i don't need, i describe the problem below, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the HTML provided, it looks like the CSS selector `div.ssl-price-box > price` will get you all the price elements you need. From there, you can use [`.getAttribute()`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) to pull the `value` attribute from each element as "377", "1288", etc. Then you would want to [convert those string values into numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766769/convert-string-array-to-integer-array), [copy that array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value), [sort the second array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), and then [compare to the first list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190181/assert-arrays-in-protractor) to verify that the two lists are sorted.

Comment: Thank you! I did everything that you wrote element.all(by.css('div.ssl-price-box > price')); but i get result not ONLY from <span class="price">
    <price value="377" units="/yr" class="lg-price ng-isolate-scope">, but from <price ng-if="product.prices.max.certIsPromo" value="21589" units="/yr" old-price="" class="base-price ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"><span class="price old-price"><span class="currency-icon">$</span><span class="integer ng-binding">215.</span><span class="cent ng-binding">89</span><span class="units">/yr</span><span class="line-through"> do i need a filter?

Comment: Which prices do you NOT want? Please update your question with the HTML of prices that you do want and then give an example of a price that you don't want. From there we should be able to come up with a locator that filters out the ones you don't want.

Comment: i create new problem, i think it will be easier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878473/i-cant-create-filter-to-extract-all-elements-that-i-need