# Jasmine toEqual not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a Jasmine test like this:

```
expect(array.length).toEqual(0);
```

This passes. Out of curiosity I changed it to:

```
expect(array.length).toEqual(false);
```

This test fails. I was under the impression that the toEqual method does a not-strict comparison. If we do

```
console.log(0 == false);
```

We get the output

```
true
```

So why is this test failing?

Comment: It does seem to be the case that `toEqual` is merely checking equivalence. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413009/javascript-using-methods-to-compare

Comment: Which jasmine version are you using?

Comment: According to what I've seen in the source code, the problem is jasmine 1.x specific. In jasmine 2.x - the test should pass (not tested though).

Comment: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wzAyL/593/

Comment: I am using Jasmine 2.3.4 actually. So it seems to still be a problem/feature.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after research: jasmine adapts underscore's isEqual method, which does a deep comparison to determine if objects should be equal. So it is a more robust comparison than javascript's standard == comparison.