# jasmine toEqual() not working on two objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine

`toEqual()` is what one would use to compare two objects in jasmine tests, right? i am puzzled as to why i am getting the following error in my test:

> Expected StoreExcludes({ id: 1, location: 'TK-LV', storeNumber: 10,
>   name: 'RIGA', ranking-level-1: true, ranking-level-2: true, all: true
>   }) to equal Object({ id: 1, location: 'TK-LV', storeNumber: 10, name:
>   'RIGA', ranking-level-1: true, ranking-level-2: true, all: true }).

any ideas?

Comment: Objects comparing isn't that simple in JS (in plain js `{foo:2}=={foo:2}` will return false). If no method was given by Jasmine, one way could be to use `JSON.stringify` on each object before comparing

Comment: @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413009/jasmine-javascript-testing-tobe-vs-toequal. Furthermore, the objects you are comparing have different types. The first one is of type StoreExcludes, the latter of plain type object. Hence, they have a different prototype and the comparison will fail.