# PhantomJS - Test failed when comparing identical objects

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I am working on a Angular.js application with Bootstrap (and jQuery). I am using Karma Jasmine with PhantomJS for testing.

I have written a test that runs a method from my controller and compares two identical objects.

```
it('should have a showDialog method which prompts a crud dialog', function () {
  ctrl.showDialog({
    id: 123,
  });
  expect(ctrl.crudDialogData).toBe({
    id: 123,
  });
});
```

The `showDialog()` method stores the argument passed in to the `crudDialogData` property.

When running my tests I receive the following error:

```
Expected Object({ id: 123 }) to be Object({ id: 123 }).
```

As far as I can see, this should be a pass. Any help?

Comment: Replace toBe with toEqual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toBe` matches by *reference*.  `toEqual` matches by *value*.  Looks like you want to use `toEqual`

Related SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27929503/803739

Comment: Ah yes, that did it. Thank you for the help!